# Ordering by letters and ignoring parentheses

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I make a selection ordering by letters and ignoring parentheses?

```
SELECT name FROM table1 ORDER BY name;
```

It returns:

```
(stu)
abc
suv
```

I would like:

```
abc
(stu)
suv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parentheses before ordering:

```
SELECT name
FROM table1
ORDER BY REPLACE(name, '(', '');
```

However, this makes it not use any index on the `name` column, so the performance will not be good if the table is big.

If the parentheses can only be one pair at the beginning and end, you can enhance the performance a bit by just removing the first character if it is a parentheses:

```
SELECT name
FROM table1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN LEFT(name, 1) = '(' THEN SUBSTR(name, 2) ELSE name END;
```

Comment: table has 4000-5000 rows. Is there another solution for selects like that?

Comment: That's not a big table, performance will be acceptable. The second query in my answer might be a bit faster, so try both and choose what you like. If you really want to enhance the performance, you'll have to create a computed column with the parentheses removed and create an index on it, then use it for the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:
`SELECT name FROM table1 ORDER BY REPLACE(name, '(', '');`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT name FROM table1 ORDER BY REPLACE(REPLACE(name, '(', ''), ')', '');
```